# CSS selector for a label of which the input is disabled

Tags: css, forms, input, css-selectors, label

I have a group of label-input sets of which some sets have a disabled input, and others have a normal input. You can see a basic example [in this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KzFL4/1/).

I want the labels of the normal inputs, to have a `pointer` cursor, whilst the other labels (of the disabled inputs) should have a `default` cursor. Is there a pure CSS way to do this? I'd need a selector for "a label which is for a disabled input" or "a label which is for a not-disabled input".

I need this to be flexible, so hardcoding the ids isn't possible (and wouldn't be neat).

Comment: I don't think you can do this with a selector. The `for` attribute simply points to the input with that ID, regardless of whether the input is disabled or not.

Comment: @BoltClock I don't expect it either, but Marc Lloyd's answer seems a nice workaround.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
input:disabled ~ label{
   cursor:default;
}
```

The label and input will need a wrapper.

Comment: This will require total restructuring of the markup in the given fiddle, however. It's not as simple as just putting them in a wrapper. The label also needs to come after the input for this to work, currently it's listed before.

Comment: Marc, I can't get this to work in my fiddle with a table. Could you show a revised version of the fiddle if possible?

Comment: The label would need to come after the input as there is currently no previous sibling selector in CSS.

I think total restructuring is a little over the top, you just need to put both the label and input within the same table cell and put the input first.